# Generate prime factors of a number in Scala

Tags: scala

How can I generate the factors of an integer in Scala? Here's my take 1:

```
def factorize(x: Int): List[Int] = {

  def foo(x: Int, a: Int): List[Int] = {

    if (a > Math.pow(x, 0.5))
      return List(x)

    x % a match {
      case 0 => a :: foo(x / a, a)
      case _ => foo(x, a + 1)
    }
  }

  foo(x, 2)
}

factorize(360) // List(2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 5)
```

**Take 2** based on comments from @SpiderPig and @seth-tisue

```
def factorize(x: Int): List[Int] = {
  def foo(x: Int, a: Int): List[Int] = {
    (a*a < x, x % a) match {
        case (true, 0) => a :: foo(x/a, a)
        case (true, _) => foo(x, a+1)
        case (false, _) => List(x)
      }
  }
  foo(x, 2)
}
```

Comment: It'd be a little better if it were tail recursive - make the list you're building into an argument

Comment: Also change `if (a > Math.pow(x, 0.5))` into `if (a * a > x)`. Math.pow is a very slow operation.

Comment: if you use `else` you don't need `return`; it's poor style to use `return` unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: @Mshnik - isn't it already tail recursive?  Also, if I make the list into an argument, I'd then need to mutate it to add items to it. Isn't it? May be I'm missing something - an example would be great.

Comment: @mpprdev `foo` is not tail-recursive, because its return value is passed as argument to `::` in `case (true, 0) => a :: foo(???)`. However, if you pass the list of prefixes to `foo` as an accumulator, then this line would change to `case (true, 0) => foo(x/a, a, prefix :+ a)`. Note that the list `prefix` is still immutable. Also, appending to a list is costly, so it's probably better to prepend to the list and reverse it in the end.

Comment: This question might be better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: This returns List(0) for factorize(0) and List(1) for factorize(1). It should be Nil

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A tail recursive solution:

```
def factorize(x: Int): List[Int] = {
  @tailrec
  def foo(x: Int, a: Int = 2, list: List[Int] = Nil): List[Int] = a*a > x match {
    case false if x % a == 0 => foo(x / a, a    , a :: list)
    case false               => foo(x    , a + 1, list)
    case true                => x :: list
  }
  foo(x)
}
```

Comment: Never mind my last edit. Just noticed that the question is looking for prime factors. Your answer is correct with tail recursion.

Answer (score 0):

Just little improvement of "Take 2" from the question:

```
def factorize(x: Int): List[Int] = {
  def foo(x: Int, a: Int): List[Int] = x % a match {
     case _ if a * a > x  => List(x)
     case 0 => a :: foo(x / a, a)
     case _ => foo(x, a + 1)
  }
  foo(x, 2)
}
```

Also, the following method may be a little faster (no `x % a` calculation in the last iteration):

```
def factorize(x: Int): List[Int] = {
  def foo(x: Int, a: Int): List[Int] = if (a * a > x) List(x) else
    x % a match {
      case 0 => a :: foo(x / a, a)
      case _ => foo(x, a + 1)
    }
  foo(x, 2)
}
```