# How can I optimize my properFractions function for Long value types

Tags: scala

I'm working on the codewars problem [Number of Proper Fractions with Denominator d](https://www.codewars.com/kata/55b7bb74a0256d4467000070/train/scala). I've tried different approaches to optimizing the solution but none of which can solve for very large numbers in the allotted time.

Does anyone have any tips for how to optimize the code?

Code: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/t0KvxqGuTMKj6zsiiEzn5Q

```
import scala.annotation.tailrec

def isPrime(n: Long): Boolean = !(2 +: (3 to Math.sqrt(n).toInt by 2) exists (n % _ == 0))
@tailrec private def gcd(a: Long, b: Long): Long = if (b == 0) a else gcd(b, a % b)

def properFractions1(n: Long): Long = {
  var product: Long = n
  var i: Long = 2
  if(n == 1) 0L
  else if(n == 2) 1L
  else {
      while(i <= n) {
          if(isPrime(i) && n%i == 0)
              product = Math.round(product * (1.0-1.0/i))
          i+=1
      }
      product
  }
}

def properFractions2(n: Long): Long = {
  Iterator.iterate(1L)(_ + 1).takeWhile(_ < n)
  .map(gcd(_,n)).filter(_ == 1).sum.toLong
}

def properFractions3(n: Long): Long = {
  val v = for(i <- 1L until n) yield {
      if(isPrime(i) && n%i != 0) 1L
      else if(gcd(i,n) == 1) 1L
      else 0L
  }
  v.sum
}

def properFractions4(n: Long): Long = {
  (1L until n).view.map(gcd(_,n)).filter(_ == 1).sum.toLong
}

properFractions1(15) // 8: Long
properFractions2(15) // 8: Long
properFractions3(15) // 8: Long
properFractions4(15) // 8: Long

// properFractions1(4665289405L)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the description of an on-line code challenge is sufficiently removed from the solution, it might qualify as [misdirection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Misdirection_(magic)).

More often than not, when you find that your perfectly good solution times out, no amount of optimization is going to fix it. It usually means that you have to rethink the basic algorithm.

For me, the "a-ha!" moment came when I realized that:

```
ProperFractions(a*b) == ProperFractions(a) * ProperFractions(b)
```

Couple that with the fact for any prime number p, `ProperFractions(p) == p-1`, and we have a strong indication that you might be able to [divide](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30280524/4993128) and conquer. (Scala solution in 9 lines of code.)